# Reference Request: Numerical Integration of Interpolation Formulas

Tags: numerical-methods, inner-products, interpolation, quadrature, discrete-calculus

I am working on a problem where I need to produce an inner product for numerical interpolation formulas. Ideally, I would like for this inner product to satisfy an integration by parts formula that looks something like the normal IBP formula from analysis, but I am a bit stuck on how to do this, and I was wondering if anyone knew of any work that has been done in this area yet? Here is the setup for the problem:

Given an analytic function $f$, we know that we can produce the $n+1$ point finite difference approximation for the $n$-th derivative of $f$ using

$$f^{(n)}(x_0) \approx \begin{pmatrix}0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & x_0 & \cdots & x_n\\1 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_n^2\\\vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots\\1 & x_0^n & \cdots & x_n^n\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}f(x_0)\\f(x_1)\\\vdots\\f(x_n)\end{pmatrix}.$$

(Note that in this definition we have to assume that the sample points are all distinct). Now, the obvious way to integrate this function is just to take $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f^{(n)}(x_i)[x_{i + 1}-x_i] = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} S^i[f^{(n)}(x_0)](x_{i + 1}-x_i)$ (here $S$ stands for the shift operator defined by $S[f(x_i)] = f(x_{i + 1})$ and we will assume that the points are ordered $x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n$), however this produces some less than desirable results, namely, integrating $f^{(n)}$ does not produce a difference between values of $f^{(n-1)}$ except for in the case where $n = 1$.

We can get a nicer formula if we define  the integral to instead be

$$\int_{x_0}^{x_{2n-1}} f^{(n)}(x_0)\,\Delta x = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f^{(n)}(x_i)[x_{n + i}-x_i] = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} S^i[f^{(n)}(x_0)](x_{n + i}-x_i)$$

(I have abused the notation slightly here. When I say $f^{(n)}(x_0)$, I actually mean it's finite difference interpolation formula with lowest value $x_0$) in which case, we can get that the integral behaves, more or less, as we would expect an integral to behave. Namely, we have that
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_{2n-1}}f^{(n)}(x_0)\,\Delta x = f^{(n-1)}(x_n) - f^{(n-1)}(x_0).$$

With this, it seems that we have found a plausible candidate for the inner product $\langle f^{(n)}, 1\rangle$, but when I try to expand this to something like $\langle f^{(n)},g^{(m)}\rangle$, everything gets really messy, so I figured before I walked down this nightmarish road of algebra, I would quickly see if anyone else knew if this has already been done before and could provide me with a reference? I have already done quite a bit of digging in my old numerics books and on MathSciNet, but I haven't been able to locate anything useful. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The inverse of a Vandermonde matrix is not always well conditioned, especially if your $x_i$ are far from $0$. Maybe you could look at another way to integrate interpolated functions? For example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: @PC1 Thank you for the recommendation. Unfortunately, the space I am working in requires that the functions I am integrating be defined using the Newton Interpolation formulas. I am, however, proceeding entirely formally, so I am not as concerned in this particular case with how sensitive my matrix is to perturbations, or how computationally accurate the inverse will be given some sample points, only that the inverse exists.